# errors messages doesn't work in HTML ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.1.6 I looked at the active record validations site and follow their direction, but nothing is displayed in the HTML even if there is an error.

However, when I do it in rails console it works.

```
post = Post.new #create an empty post to test
post.valid? #false
post.errors.messages #this is successfully generate the error message array
```

However, it doesn't display any error messages in HTML. In fact "@post.errors" doesn't even run

-Ruby code in html

```
<%= form_for @post, :method => :post do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :url %>
  <%= f.text_field :url %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

  <% if @errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @errors.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

-My PostsController

```
def create
  # post = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], url: params[:post][:url])
  post = Post.new(post_params)
  if post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    @errors = post.errors.messages
    redirect_to paths_path
  end
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :url)
  end
```

-My post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :length => {maximum: 140, minimum:1}, :presence => true
  validates :title, :length => {maximum: 2083, minimum:1}, :allow_blank => true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to errors I do like to have a partial so I can keep my errors the same in the whole app like so:

**app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb:**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
 <h5>The <%= t("activerecord.models.#{object.class.to_s.downcase}") %> could not be saved due to the following errors:</h5>

      <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
<% end %>
```

And then for the views you want the errors to be displayed, just call:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', object: @your_object %>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Got some tip from my teacher it work. Simply use flash[:message] and it worked. Sorry for the trouble everyone

-My controller code

```
def create
  post = Post.new(post_params)
  if post.save
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:message] = post.errors.messages
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

-My HTML code

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :method => :post do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :url %>
  <%= f.text_field :url %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  <%= flash[:message] %>

<% end %>
```